# Add multiple entities to JavaScript namespace from different files

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton, namespaces

Given a namespaces `ns` used in two different files:

#### abc.js

```
ns = ns || (function () {
   foo = function() { ... };

   return {
      abc : foo
   };
}());
```

#### def.js

```
// is this correct?
ns = ns || {}

ns.def = ns.def || (function () {
   defoo = function () { ... };
   return {
      deFoo: defoo
   };
}());
```

Is this the proper way to add `def` to the `ns` to a namespace? In other words, how does one merge two contributions to a namespace in javascript?

If `abc.js` comes before `def.js` I'd expect this to work. If `def.js` comes before `abc.js` I'd expect `ns.abc` to not exist because `ns` is defined at the time.

It seems there ought to be a design pattern to eliminate any uncertainty of doing inclusions with the javascript namespace pattern.

I'd appreciate thoughts and input on how best to go about this sort of 'inclusion'.

Thanks for reading.

Brian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a javascript namespace into multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150124/splitting-a-javascript-namespace-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would certainly work. Keep in mind, though, that source order will affect your implementation: if def.js ever winds up included before abc.js, your definition of foo and ns.abc will never be executed.

Take a look at [YUI's old namespace function for an example](http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/master/src/yahoo/js/YAHOO.js#L98): they make sure either use the existing object or a new object initialization, probably for that reason above.

It might very well help you to keep your modules separate with something like this:

```
ns = ns || {};
ns.abc = function(){ ... }();

and 

ns = ns || {};
ns.def = function() ... }();
```

That way, each is a separate module, source order doesn't matter, and each has access to its own closure as you have in your example.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of interest, I discovered [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) and [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and started using that.