# Splitting a JavaScript namespace into multiple files

Tags: javascript, namespaces, code-organization

Let's say I have a namespace like that:

```
var myNamespace = {
    foo: function() {
    },
    bar: function() {
    }
};
```

What is the best way to split this code into files defining `foo` and `bar` separately?

I'm not worried about loading time - I'll concatenate it back into one file before deployment.

Comment: Vote up for an excellent question! Taught me something good.

Comment: Also mentioned at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4130511/895245

Answer (score 48, accepted):

At the start of each file:

```
if(myNameSpace === undefined) {
  var myNameSpace = {};
}
```

File 1:

```
myNamespace.foo = function()...
```

File 2:

```
myNamespace.bar = function()...
```

Answer (score 14):

```js
// File1:
// top level namespace here:
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};

// File2:
myNamespace.foo = function() {
    // some code here...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In each file follow this pattern:

```
(function(nameSpace) {
    nameSpace.foo = function() { ... };
})(window.nameSpace = window.nameSpace || {});
```

This way load ordering is unimportant.

Answer (score 3):

Simple define in seperate files like this:

File 1:

```
var myNamspace = {};
```

File 2:

```
myNamespace.foo = function()...
```

File 3:

```
myNamespace.boo = function()...
```

Just make sure you load the files in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function (NS) {
    NS.Uber = function Uber() {
        this.super = new NS.Super(); // yes, it works!
    }; //
}(NS = NS || {}));

// ------------- other file -----------------

(function (NS) {
    NS.Super = function Super() {
        this.uber = new NS.Uber(); // yes, it will also work!
    }; //
}(NS = NS || {}));

// -------------- application code ------------

var uber = new NS.Uber();
console.log(uber.super);

var super = new NS.Super();
console.log(super.uber);
```

Comment: NS = NS || {} means that it sends NS as an argument, and if nonexistent, it assigns an empty object into NS.

Comment: This triggers a Reference Error : NS is undefined when trying to execute the line `}(NS = NS || {}));` [see this jsfiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/6cyrx3ad/)